# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) os_info.id may not be NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy table object and try to insert some values, but it raises error like

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) os_info.id may not be NULL'
```

I can't understand how this happened, as I assigned Column `id` with `autoincrement=True`

```
class Os(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'os_info'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    hostname = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
    dist = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
    instruct_set = Column(String(32), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Os(hostname='%s',dist='%s',instruct_set='%s')>" % (self.hostname, self.dist, self.instruct_set)
```

Comment: Define the `id` column as `Sequence` type instead.

Comment: Are you sure the actual schema in the DB matches your models here?